# Spring Boot Maven Plugin build-image error: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin, cloud-native

Mac os version :  13.5.2 (22G91)
processor: 1.4 GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i5

jvm version: java 17.0.2 2022-01-18 LTS
springboot version : 2.4.3
maven version: Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)

Docker version:
Client:
Cloud integration: v1.0.35-desktop+001
Version:           24.0.5
API version:       1.43
Go version:        go1.20.6
Git commit:        ced0996
Built:             Fri Jul 21 20:32:30 2023
OS/Arch:           darwin/amd64
Context:           desktop-linux

Server: Docker Desktop 4.22.1 (118664)
Engine:
Version:          24.0.5
API version:      1.43 (minimum version 1.12)
Go version:       go1.20.6
Git commit:       a61e2b4
Built:            Fri Jul 21 20:35:45 2023
OS/Arch:          linux/amd64
Experimental:     false
containerd:
Version:          1.6.21
GitCommit:        3dce8eb055cbb6872793272b4f20ed16117344f8
runc:
Version:          1.1.7
GitCommit:        v1.1.7-0-g860f061
docker-init:
Version:          0.19.0
GitCommit:        de40ad0

When I run the following command under my maven project: `mvn -e  spring-boot:build-image`, the following failure occurs:

```
[INFO]  > Running creator
[INFO]     [creator]     Warning: Platform requested deprecated API '0.4'
[INFO]     [creator]     ===> DETECTING
[INFO]     [creator]     ERROR: failed to initialize detector: toml: line 1: files cannot contain NULL bytes; probably using UTF-16; TOML files must be UTF-8
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  27.387 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-09-09T09:43:41+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image (default-cli) on project advertising: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 1 -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image (default-cli) on project advertising: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 1

Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-maven-plugin:2.6.4:build-image failed: Builder lifecycle 'creator' failed with status code 1
```

But when I run the same command on another Mac with an M1 chip, all things work just fine. After many tries, including version adjusting or OS upgrade, I still have no clues, so I need some help or hints!

What I want: I just want to use the buildpacks plugin normally.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Not sure of the root cause, but I noticed error output related to `TOML` files, a `UTF-8` format requirement, and a suggestion that your file may be in `UTF-16` format. I suggest resolving that problem as a first step and proceeding from that point.

Comment: yes, I also noticed this info, it seems happened during the detecting step when buildpacks plugin run, but  I still  don't know how to find that exact file which reported as wrong format